# Issue with buttons placement in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am facing some problem in button placement. I am developing an app in which when app starts camera opens (customized). I have added 2 buttons in the Layout, My problem is I am unable to adjust the buttons. I want buttons to placed like capture button will be at bottom in center, and upload button will be at bottom in right. I am using following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

</FrameLayout>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_upload"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:text="Upload"
       />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_capture"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
      android:text="Capture" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried with LinearLayout. Can anyone tell me where I am making mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

in Button tag

Comment: this has moved the button to center, fine. and how would I move button to right? Also why I am unable to just drag the button and place where ever I want?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_upload"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_weight="1" >

  </FrameLayout>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_upload"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Upload" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_capture"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_upload"
      android:text="Capture" />

</RelativeLayout>`enter code here`
```

Comment: why marginRight 55dp? It worked. Can you please explain what mistakes I was making so that I could avoid next time. Also why I am unable to just drap and place the button where ever I want with mouse?

Comment: I just changed Framlayout width from fill parent to wrap content...And then set the margin from Upload button...

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out this can be done like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="#A9A9A9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_capture"
    />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_capture"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="Capture" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_upload"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:text="Upload" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```